# Vagrant is not forwarding when I run django runserver on ssh

Tags: django, windows, virtualbox, vagrant

I created a Vagrant Ubuntu (lucid32) box with Python & Django. My idea is start the VM, log into it with `vagrant ssh`, and then start Django by running:

```
manage.py runserver
```

which defaults to port 8000. The problem is that I can not access the Django server from the host's browser at `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. What can I do?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You need to bind the server to the external IP with:

```
manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to do port forwarding in Vagrant file.

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
```

Then you need to restart/reload your vangrant vm

```
vagrant reload
```

Now ssh to your vm and run django server as follows

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```