# How can I use Django Development Server with VM(Vagrant and VirtualBox)?

Tags: python, django, ssh, vagrant, vagrantfile

I can see the "It Works!" page with my Django project host machine!

When I 
`vagrant ssh` (enter into the VM) and then in /myprojectdir `python manage.py runserver` or

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` or

`python manage.py runserver 10.0.2.2 (guest IP):8000` or

`python manage.py runserver 10.0.2.2 (host IP):8000`  it says

> No issues (0)silenced...Date ...
>
> Django Version 1.8.7...
>
> Starting development server at...http://X.X.X.X:XXXX

Ok, great- I'll check the address to see the page but

**I do not** see the 'It works!' page.  And instead I see text in the top left corner of the page

> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1

.

[Binding the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255203/vagrant-is-not-forwarding-when-i-run-django-runserver-on-ssh) or [using the Guest's own IP address](https://coderwall.com/p/qnkojw/django-dev-server-in-vagrant) have not worked.

Note: the VM I'm using is a CentOS7 box *but* I tried this on the [vagrant tutorial standard box, Precise32,](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/boxes.html) and it behaved the same as I described above.

Food for thought:

- Again the Django side of things is working; I can use the same file to `python manage.py runserver` in the *host* (works) but not when I'm on the VM (does not work).
- I'm using a NAT connection and when I try to use a bridged connection vagrant requests a password which I don't know (can't access via bridging).
- I've included: `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 8000, id: 'ssh'` in my Vagrantfile.  Otherwise vagrant defaults to port 2222.

What do I have to change in the Vagrantfile to get the Django Development Server- the 'It works!'- page up-and-running on my VM?

**Current Vagrantfile**

```
    Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.1"
  config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 8000, id: 'ssh'
  config.vm.synced_folder "myApp", "/myApp"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "1024"
  end
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "vagrant-setup.sh"
end
```

Comment: try this: `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8000, host: 8000  # Django webapp` and run django from within the VM with: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but since it said`* Forwarded port '8000' (host port) is declared multiple times with the protocol 'tcp'.` I tried making host:8001 and it _went through_ but still with the same result as my original question.

Comment: Remove previous `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 8000, id: 'ssh'`

Answer (score 0):

`config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 8000, id: 'ssh'` forwards the port 22 on your guest machine (VM) to port 8000 on your host.

because you want port 8000, you should replace it with with

`config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8000, host: 8000`

Comment: Thanks @fab. When I tried to vagrant reload and/or vagrant ssh it endlessly repeats `default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...`